# tkintertable, how to block/disable columns or cells

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using `tkintertable` in Python 3, how can I make `tkintertable` column or cell read-only as we do in ttk.Entry or other tkinter widget? For example:

`Entry(frame,state=DISABLED).`

Comment: Set attribute `read_only` to `True`.

Comment: This would set the whole table to read only. What I need is for specific columns/cells only.